# Using several self interpreters

Tags: self-interpreter

I tested a sslf interpreter, and put up to 4 of them together.

I noticed that everytime I add a self-interpreter the running time increased exponential.
Can anyone explain me what happens, and why it increases at such speed when increasing the amount of self-interpreters on simple arithmetics.

Comment: This isn't clear.  You're saying you've written a self-interpreter, and you're now running 4 instances inside each other?

Comment: Yes, adding the same self-interpreter 4 times on the same aritmethic calculation.

Comment: Well, it makes sense.  If on average interpreting 1 statement takes N statements, then doing that 4 times recursively will be N*N*N*N.